# creating an instance of my character

Tags: java

I have this silly little issue that I just can't wrap my mind around, it is so simple but I just can't figure it out and I can't find how to do it, I have been reading libGDX tutorials for a while now, I am using different parts from everywhere to create my own side scrolling game.

I have this class:

```
package com.gibbo.bounce.model;

import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class Gib {


    public static final float SPEED = 5f;
    public static final float BOUNCE_HEIGHT = 8f;
    public static final float GIB_HEIGHT = 4f;
    public static final float GIB_WIDTH = 1.5f;

    Vector2 position = new Vector2();
    Vector2 acceleration = new Vector2();
    Vector2 velocity = new Vector2();
    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle();

    public Gib(Vector2 position){
        this.position = position;
        this.bounds.height = GIB_HEIGHT;
        this.bounds.width = GIB_WIDTH;
    }

    public Vector2 getPosition(){
        return position;
    }

    public Vector2 getAcceleration(){
        return acceleration;
    }

    public Vector2 getVelocity(){
        return velocity;
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds(){
        return bounds;
    }


}
```

So this is my player character, I need to import him and render him but I literally have no idea how, the funny thing is.... I can type up the code to render a rectangle IN the game screen class complete with accel movement and side collisions but I just have no idea how to take this class and use the properties from that...fail.

Someone got an idea, I presume it straight forward lol.

EDIT: I have tried using a constructor `Gib gib = new Gib()`; to no avail, throws errors, lack of constructor? what have I missed here :S

Comment: Well yes - the only constructor you've declared takes a `Vector2` parameter, so calling `new Gib()` definitely wouldn't work...

Comment: so basically I need to create a constructor that takes int x, int y as the arguements? would this not completely mess up the public Vector2 getPosition() method?

Comment: I don't see how you took that from my response - can you not create a `Vector2` from your `x` and `y` values?

Comment: Because I am very bad at Java lol, this is new to me, well the language I have been learning for a couple of weeks but using gdxLib is new. could you clarify what you mean by creating a Vector2 from the x and y?...sorry

Comment: nvm I see it `code`Gib gib = new Gib(Vector2(x, y));`code`

Comment: @Gibbo This boils down to you using `new Gib()` to test constructing your `Gib` object, rather than the constructor you already have with a `Vector2` argument. Have you tested creating a `Gib` object by passing in a `Vector2` object to the `Gib` constructor? So far all of the answers here are saying you need to have a defined 0-arg constructor in order to use `new Gib()`, which is true if you want to use that, but what Jon is saying is that you need to use `new Gib(aVector2Obj)` instead. (edit: I shoulda hit post a few seconds sooner :P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 0-argument constructor for your class `Gib`.  You need to either create a 0 argument constructor `public class Gib(){}` or call the constructor with the `Vector2` parameter that you already created.

Comment: I am selecting you for the best answer for the simple fact you told me to call the constructor, which was fairly obious but yeah, me being dumb. Thanks to Jon Skeet as well

Comment: @Gibbo you have to click the little check mark over to the left under the arrows in order to select the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a constructor with no parameters, to call a constructor with no parameters.

However, this may or may not be the correct way for you to go. Since your `Gib` requires a vector position(and other vectors as well), you should obtain or construct this vector, and pass it into the existing constructor.

Comment: No, there's no indication that the right solution here is to add a parameterless constructor. I think it's more likely that the right solution is for the OP to create a `Vector2` to represent the appropriate position, and then call the existing constructor.

Comment: @JonSkeet It's hard for me to tell what the intentions are since there are other important vectors as well.

Comment: @hexafraction: Indeed - we don't have a lot of context - but claiming that the OP *needs* to create a parameterless constructor feels misleading to me. It suggests that's the *only* solution here.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried using a constructor Gib gib = new Gib(); to no avail,
>   throws errors, lack of constructor? what have I missed here :S

As you calling the default constructor but but there is no default constructor in your class.So  you  need to provide

```
public Gib(){

    }
```

Comment: sometimes it happens :)

Comment: Hehe unfotunately yours ones right under a certain situation, however I needed to use the Vector2 construtor! I just forgot the code for it haha. Maybe next time :D